# How to get multiple inputs of String when the number of input string is n

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working with a question for that we need to get n string inputs how to store then in n string variables.

I tried with array storing the string in each elements

Is there any other way in java ?

Comment: You'd use an array or collection of some kind.

Comment: As @David mentioned, try using a Collection. I suggest **ArrayList**

Comment: Here you can use some implementations of list(e.g.ArrayList), the reason why not Set for instance, is that you will loose some strings if they are the same. In you case, as I understand, you need to store [N] string no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on how you are getting that N, if N is first input then you can take that input and make array of that size like:

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
String[] array = new String[n];
```

Or if you just want to add until X input which will stop it then you can use arraylist like this:

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
```

Collections are dynamic so you don't need to specify number of elements in advance. You simple add elements:

`array.add("somestring");` or `array.add(stringVariableName);`

Comment: thank you for your answer Filip .    but if we go with string list is't easy to traverse the list more than 1 time...if i want to know the i th value and i th value may be shuffled ...

Comment: Actually collections have method for shuffling `Collections.shuffle(yourList);`, and arraylist works with index similar to regular arrays, when you are getting element you can write `array.get(index);` and there is also method `array.indexOf(object);` which returns index of first occurrence of provided object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in advance how many strings to save in memory, then you can use dynamic constructs like implementers of List (e.g.: ArrayList) if you want to store all the lists preserving the order, or Sets (e.g.: HashSet) if you don't want store duplicates and you don't care the order in which they were inserted.